# In Selenium how can I check if I have scrolled the page till the end

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There is scenario to automated in which the list of element is loaded dynamically at run time in chunks, every time you scroll the page it will fetch somedata and will display. Now I need to check if I have reached to the bottom of the page after scrolling. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this helper to check:

```
var _getDocHeight = function() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
};
var isScrolledToBottom = function() {
    return (window.innerHeight + window.top.scrollY) == _getDocHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);

js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This will scroll to the bottom of the page but not check if your page is scrolled to the bottom

Comment: Thank you RNS for your comment